# HTML Select on change sum values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sum some values `onChange` HTML select box. My problem is that when I change selected value the value on "display" does not change.

```js
var Price = document.getElementById("price"),
  PriceSValue = Price.value;

var sum = 0;
var a = PriceSValue;
var b = '1000';
sum = a + b;

document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<select id="price" class="form-control" name="two">
  <option value="100">Monthly</option>
  <option value="200">3 month</option>
  <option value="300">6 month</option>
  <option value="400">6 month</option>
</select>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: look into data types. you adding 2 strings, not 2 numbers. You need to convert them to numbers by either using `parseFloat` or `parseInt`

Comment: I don't see any `change` event handler anywhere in the shown code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an event listener to the `select#price` element, you need to either add it via JavaScript (preferred) or inline with the HTML markup.

Also, you should use integer values instead of strings. If you add a number to a string, it is treated as normal string concatenation.

**Note:** Not sure why you have "6 month" twice. Are these computations supposed to be multiplicative rather than additive?

### JavaScript Only

```js
const initialValue = 1000, fee = 50;
const priceSelect = document.querySelector('#price');
const display = document.querySelector('#display');

const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

const onPriceChange = (e) => {
  const amount = +e.target.value; // Access value; cast to number '+';
  const total = initialValue + amount + fee;
  display.textContent = currencyFormatter.format(total);
};

priceSelect.addEventListener('change', onPriceChange);

onPriceChange({ target: priceSelect });
```

```html
<select id="price" class="form-control" name="two">
  <option value="100">Monthly</option>
  <option value="200">3 month</option>
  <option value="300">6 month</option>
  <option value="400">6 month</option>
</select>
<div id="display"></div>
```

### HTML + JavaScript

```js
const initialValue = 1000, fee = 50;
const priceSelect = document.querySelector('#price');
const display = document.querySelector('#display');

const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

const onPriceChange = (e) => {
  const amount = +e.target.value; // Access value; cast to number '+';
  const total = initialValue + amount + fee;
  display.textContent = currencyFormatter.format(total);
};

// Added as an attribute to HTML => onChange="onPriceChange(event)
//priceSelect.addEventListener('change', onPriceChange);

onPriceChange({ target: priceSelect });
```

```html
<select id="price" class="form-control" name="two" onChange="onPriceChange(event)">
  <option value="100">Monthly</option>
  <option value="200">3 month</option>
  <option value="300">6 month</option>
  <option value="400">6 month</option>
</select>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: you really don't like `function`s do you?

Comment: @tacoshy ES6 all the way 

Comment: hoisting has nothing to do with ES6

Comment: @tacoshy in terms of arrow/lambda expressions. Well, I prefer a functional approach over hoisting.

Comment: Code is OK and what if I want to add sum Fee number with them?

Comment: @SeyyedMohammadHosseini If you need another variable, add it to the equation. I updated my code to show an added "fee".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `onChange=""` event, so it will call a function which will sum your values. You can pass the selection value by adding an argument to the function using `this.value`. Furthermore, you need to convert every number into an `int`, so it will sum up.

```js
function sumAndChangeDisplay(price) {
      var b = 1000;
      var sum = parseInt(price) + b;
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = sum;
    }
```

```html
<select onChange="sumAndChangeDisplay(this.value)" id="price" class="form-control" name="two">
    <option value="100">Monthly</option>
    <option value="200">3 month</option>
    <option value="300">6 month</option>
    <option value="400">6 month</option>
</select>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```js
function updateTotal() {
    var Price = document.getElementById("price");
    var PriceSValue = Number(Price.value);

    var sum = 0;
    var a = PriceSValue;
    var b = 1000;  // Notice the change here to make it a number, not a string
    sum = a + b;

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = sum;
}

// Attach the update function to the select box's change event
document.getElementById("price").addEventListener("change", updateTotal);
```

```html
<select id="price" class="form-control" name="two" onChange="updateTotal()">
    <option value="100">Monthly</option>
    <option value="200">3 month</option>
    <option value="300">6 month</option>
    <option value="400">6 month</option>
</select>
<div id="display"></div>
```